# Drive-by clicking causes event not to fire

Tags: silverlight, button, click, mouse

In a standard, unstyled button in Silverlight. It lives in a ChildWindow.

While the cursor is still moving, I click the button but the event does not fire.

I am sure the first click is happening inside the button and the release of the mouse also inside.  The diagram illustrates approximately where I first click and where I end up.  I am not dragging but releasing the mouse button as quickly as possible.

[image]

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <Grid x:Name="MainContent" Grid.Row="0">
         <!-- MainContent here -->
    </Grid>


    <Grid  Grid.Row="1">
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                           Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"
                        Click="CancelButton_Click" />
                    <Button   
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Width="{StaticResource CenterButtonWidth}"                           
                        Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="false" />
                    <Button          
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        Style="{StaticResource ButtonTwoToneStyle2}" 
                        Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="true" />
                </Grid>
            </ContentControl>
    </Grid> 
</Grid>
```

Comment: To add on to this, I can just press, hold  and release and duplicate the behavior.  My guess is that something in the visual tree may be causing the event to be lost, but I don't really know where to start looking.

Comment: I've pared it down a bit, but that's the gist of it.  It lives in a custom ChildWindow.

Comment: Your first button has both a command and a click event handler.  Is that by design?

Comment: @Robaticus Yes, the first command fires the business logic and the event handler closes the dialog.  When I notice the anomaly, neither fire.

Comment: More then likely, I've got something funny going in the VisualTree that I am not aware of...